# Sub panel wire run

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I am trying to install a 60 amp sub panel in my house to power my wife's saltwater tanks. I know I need 6/3 to go from main panel to sub panel. My question is I have to run it along the wall to get to the ceiling then down the wall to get to sub panel. What type of wire and do I need conduit? The sub panel will be just outside the backdoor under the porch. Coming out of main panel the wire will be exposed upto ceiling then over about 2 feet at which time will go into ceiling. Then will come out porch ceiling outback into the sub panel. Project is on hold to I can get clarification.

Comment: Not just *any* 6/3.  You need 6/3 UF, or other outdoor rated cable.   What you can't use is 6/3 NM or Romex.

Comment: Are you running the wire up the outside of the house, or out the back of the panel into the wall?

Comment: Yes had to repost this question with further information.  The wire will be ran through the roof trusses over to the patio ceiling which it will them be dropped down through it outside along patio wall down to box. Exposed wire length will be about 2ft.

Comment: You didn't need to repeat. You needed to click the [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/161191/edit) link and revise the post.

Answer (score 0):

Decisions on what type of system you need to install and where are usually about what kind of protection is needed to prevent damage to the conductors. All of these systems can be found in Chapter 3 of the NEC "Wiring Methods and Materials. Each article will have a type of system and each article will list where they are approved and where they are not approved. Then it comes down to if you want to switch different systems in different areas or do you want to choose one system that covers all conditions.

Maybe we can be more explicit if you will reword your question and be more specific about the locations you are running it though. For example if you are running it along the wall. Is the wall on the exterior or the interior? Is it subject to machine or people traffic or is it out of reach? And if you want one cable or conduit system or use different systems in different areas for cost, access and labor concerns.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Ok. My main panel is in the garage on a wall directly below my bonus room. There is no access to go directly up inside the wall. I need to bring the feed out of the wall then up to the ceiling. Running it in the open over to a point I can put it up into the crawl space. Then running it through the crawl space to where I can drop it down through the patio ceiling into the subpanel I will be mounting on the outside. I have to put it here due to the limitations of proper clearance for the subpanel.